# Why "guests2.update(guests1)" is returning "None" instead of an updated dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, automation, shortcut

Taylor and Rory are hosting a party. They sent out invitations, and each one collected responses into dictionaries, with names of their friends and how many guests each friend is bringing. Each dictionary is a partial list, but Rory's list has more current information about the number of guests. We have to combine both dictionaries into one, with each friend listed only once, and the number of guests from Rory's dictionary taking precedence, if a name is included in both dictionaries. Then print the resulting dictionary.

I did this code:

```
def combine_guests(guests1, guests2):
  # Combine both dictionaries into one, with each key listed 
  # only once, and the value from guests1 taking precedence
  return guests2.update(guests1)

Rorys_guests = { "Adam":2, "Brenda":3, "David":1, "Jose":3, "Charlotte":2, "Terry":1, "Robert":4}
Taylors_guests = { "David":4, "Nancy":1, "Robert":2, "Adam":1, "Samantha":3, "Chris":5}

print(combine_guests(Rorys_guests, Taylors_guests))
```

and OUTPUT is:
None

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
//A new dictionary with the keys and values of both dictionary by giving precedence to first dictionary.

Comment: In Python, functions either return a new object or they update an object in place. The latter don't usually return anything.

Comment: What makes you think `update` should return something rather than just modify the object? Did you not read the documentation of `dict`?